# How to change the a vector from a base class via a derived class function

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance

I have made a base class called Shape_2D, which would be inherited by all the shapes class

Shape_2D.h

```
private:
    std::vector<Point> points_within_shape_;
    std::vector<Point> points_on_perimeter_;

public:
    std::vector<Point> get_Points_Within_Shape();
    std::vector<Point> get_Points_On_Perimeter();
```

There's only 1 constructor for the Shape_2D class
Shape_2D.cpp

```
Shape_2D::Shape_2D(const std::string &name, const bool &contain_Warp_Space)
    : name_(name), contain_warp_space_(contain_Warp_Space) {}

std::vector<Point> Shape_2D::get_Points_Within_Shape()
{
    return this->points_within_shape_;
}

std::vector<Point> Shape_2D::get_Points_On_Perimeter()
{
    return this->points_on_perimeter_;
}
```

Given the code above, I want to get all the points within a shape (Rectangle in this case) and have it return a vector for all the points.

The function for that is implemented individually for each shape
This example is the rectangle class

Rectangle.h

```
    std::vector<Point> get_All_Point_In_Shape() override;
    std::vector<Point> get_All_Point_On_Shape() override;
```

In the Constructor of Rectangle, I immediately tried to assign the vector using the function defined below.

Rectangle.cpp

```
Rectangle::Rectangle(const std::array<Point, 4> &vertices, const bool &warp_space)
    : Shape_2D("Rectangle", warp_space), vertices_(vertices), area_(compute_Area())
{
    get_Points_Within_Shape() = get_All_Point_In_Shape();
    get_Points_On_Perimeter() = get_All_Point_On_Shape();
}

std::vector<Point> Rectangle::get_All_Point_In_Shape()
{
    std::vector<Point> points_within_shape;
    for (int x = vertices_[0].get_X() + 1; x < vertices_[2].get_X(); x++)
    {
        for (int y = vertices_[1].get_Y() + 1; y < vertices_[0].get_Y(); y++)
        {
            if (is_Point_In_Shape(x, y))
                points_within_shape.push_back(Point(x, y));
        }
    }
    return points_within_shape;
}

std::vector<Point> Rectangle::get_All_Point_On_Shape()
{
    std::vector<Point> points_on_perimeter;
    for (int x = vertices_[0].get_X(); x <= vertices_[2].get_X(); x++)
    {
        for (int y = vertices_[1].get_Y(); y <= vertices_[0].get_Y(); y++)
        {
            if (is_Point_On_Shape(x, y))
                points_on_perimeter.push_back(Point(x, y));
        }
    }
    return points_on_perimeter;
}
```

However, when i run them through the debugger, i find out that despite the function works properly, the vector declared in Shape_2D will not update accordingly. Is there something i can do to fix this?

Comment: _How to change the a vector from a base class via a derived class function_ Either make the member variable `protected` or provide a `protected` function in the base class for modification. `protected` is the intermediate between `private` and `public` which expands access just to derived classes. (`friend` is the other option, of course, but might not be appropriate in your specific case.)

Comment: Hi Yosua. Please provide some feedback, did you manage to solve your problem? Was the given answer helpful? If it did, please consider up-voting and marking it as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you defined functions `get_Points_Within_Shape()` and `get_Points_On_Perimeter()` as returning **copies** of internal vectors. Instead you should define them to return **references** to internal vectors. Also, usually there are 2 versions for such functions: usual function returning usual vector and `const` function returning `const` vector. I.e. your declaration should look something like this:

```
std::vector<Point>& get_Points_Within_Shape() {return points_within_shape_;}
const std::vector<Point>& get_Points_Within_Shape() const {return points_within_shape_;}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that methods `get_Points_Within_Shape` and `get_Points_On_Perimeter` are returning a copy of the points vector, so you basically just assign to that copy, which is then destroyed after the statement execution is finished (because it was not saved into a variable).

Your options here would be to either make `points_within_shape_` and `points_on_perimeter_` protected, so the deriving class can access them (like suggested in the comments), or to provide overload for a getter function that allows modifying the data:

```
std::vector<Point> &get_Points_Within_Shape()
{
    return points_within_shape_;
}    
const std::vector<Point> &get_Points_Within_Shape() const
{
    return points_within_shape_;
}
```

Notice that first method provides ability to access the data, since it returns a non-const reference. Another alternative would be to implement a setter in the base class:

```
void set_Points_Within_Shape(const std::vector<Point> &points)
{
    points_within_shape_ = points;
}
```

Even if you decide to use a setter, you should still change your getter class to return `const std::vector<Point> &`. This way, you won't copy all the points into a new vector each time you want to read them. If there are many points in the vector, this can be major performance penalty.

P.S.
Although it is the simplest way, please avoid declaring the derived class a `friend`. This should be used only in some specific cases, and definitely not in a case where one class is inheriting from another.